# Can't solve $(A \setminus B) \setminus C = (A\setminus C) \setminus (B \setminus C) = A \setminus (B \cup C)$ any help?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have discrete math exam and i can't quite figure out one example.

$(A \setminus B) \setminus C = (A\setminus C) \setminus (B \setminus C) = A \setminus (B \cup C)$

i tried solving it like this and i got stuck:
$(A \setminus B) \setminus C = (A \cap \bar B) \cap \bar C$, "what next ? :D"

Comment: $(A\setminus B) \setminus C = (A \cap \bar B)\cap\bar C = A \cap (\bar B \cap \bar C) = A \cap \overline{(B \cup C)} = A \setminus (B \cup C)$.

Comment: Is one direction easier than another? Can you take any of the three expressions and show that set is *included* in another one of the expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely, we have to apply the following properties of set operations ($\forall A:~\bar A$ is $A$'s complement):

1. De Morgan's first law: $\forall A, B:~\overline{(A\cup B)} = \bar A \cap \bar B$.
2. Interpretation of set difference: $\forall A,B:~A\setminus B = A \cap \bar B$.

Now, we can rewrite you original equation as follows:

$$(A\setminus B) \setminus C = [\text{by prop. (2)}]=(A \cap \bar B)\setminus C = (A \cap \bar B)\cap \bar C =\\= [\text{since set intersection is associative}] =\\=A \cap (\bar B \cap \bar C) =[\text{by prop. (1)}] = A \cap \overline{(B \cup C)} = [\text{by prop. (2)}] = A \setminus (B \cup C).$$

Comment: OMG i am so dumb i was trying to get to this (A-C)-(B-C) from (A-B)-C :D btw ty.

Comment: @itmemilan no problem, sometimes all what you need is just some simple properties, so that solve the task and not to overcomplicate it :)